# U-Boot: TI Sitara AM335X MII connected to Marvell switch

Tags: linux, beagleboneblack, u-boot

We have a new board based on the AM335X Beaglebone black. I am using the Beagle U-Boot and Kernel and it looks that everything is working except Networking. The difference is that in our board the AM3352 is connected via MII to a Marvell 5 ports switch (88e6341).

What modifications should I do in the U-Boot source code (or also in the Kernel) in order to support that architecture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution how to modify the u-boot in order to support boards based on the beagle bone black and instead of Ethernet PHY, it has Marvell Switch (in my case it is 88e6341) connected with MII:

First, use Fix PHY driver - the only issue that it aimed to work with DT, so if it is not ETH DT - change the code to ignore the CONFIG. Make sure the software takes the Fix driver as the port phy driver. Set it hardcoded to 100 MB speed, and Full Duplex.

The other issue is the initialization of the switch CPU port and switch ports:

In the routine board_eth_init (in board.c) add the following initializations (after the cpsw initialization):

```
// Set port 0,1,2 to forwarding Mode (through Switch Port registers)

miiphy_write(name, 16,4, 0x7f);
miiphy_write(name, 17,4, 0x7f);
miiphy_write(name, 18,4, 0x7f);

/* RGMII Delay on Port 0 (CPU port), force link to 100Mbps */

miiphy_write(name, 16,1, 0x283d);

/* Power up PHY 1, 2, 3 (through Global 2 registers) */
miiphy_write(name, 28,25, 0x1140);
miiphy_write(name, 28,24, 0x9620);
miiphy_write(name, 28,24, 0x9640);
miiphy_write(name, 28,24, 0x9660);
```

In the kernel code just change in the file iam335x-bone-common.dts:

```
   &cpsw_emac0 {

\-       phy_id = <&davinci_mdio>, <0>;

\+       fixed-link = <1 1 100 0 0>;

phy-mode = "mii";

 };
```

Good Luck

Avner

Answer (score 0):

In U-Boot, very roughly, you'll want to change board/ti/am335x/board.c::board_eth_init to setup what you have, rather than the default choices and at least review board/ti/am335x/mux.c to ensure you're still setting pinmux as you need it.  And you'll want to enable an appropriate ethernet driver.

Then for the Linux Kernel you'll need to write a device tree that describes your hardware correctly, based on what you changed from the reference platform.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The pinmux I have is correct.